# displaying image full screen - loses quality android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-fullscreen

I'm trying to display image full screen but seems that the image loses quality. I get the image from an URL, I download it and when I'm displaying the images, it looks pretty bad. The images that I'm getting are in high resolution so I do not know what can the problem be?

Here is my Layout where i'm displaying the image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/full_screen_banner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

and here is the java code:

```
imageViews.put(imageView, url);
Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
if (bitmap != null)
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: what type of library are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using image loader just go to `imageloader` class then

Check these lines

```
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }
        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```